# How is a dylib added to the OSX project in CBuilder XE4

Tags: macos, linker, c++builder, dylib

I have windows/OSX/C++Builder XE4 app with a zmq.dll/zmq.lib and a zmq.dylib.  The windows app builds and runs fine but I have not been able to determine how the dylib becomes part of the OSX project to resolve the externals and build successfully.

Comment: A `.dylib` file is the equivalent of a `.dll` file. I do not know if there is an equivalent of an import `.lib` file for a `.dylib` file, but you could use `SafeLoadLibrary()` and `dlsym()` to load a function dynamically, like with `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` on Windows.